# Did I understand /dev/urandom?

Tags: linux, unix, random, cryptography

I have been reading about `/dev/urandom`, and as far as I can tell, `/dev/random` creates cryptographically random numbers by taking advantage of several events like network packet timings, etc. However, did I understand right that `/dev/urandom` uses a PRNG, seeded with a number from `/dev/random`? Or does it just use `/dev/random` as long as there are bits -- and when they run out it falls back to some PRNG with a seed gathered from where?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From the `urandom` manpage:

> The random number generator gathers
>   environmental noise from device
>   drivers and other sources into an
>   entropy pool.  The generator also
>   keeps an estimate of the number of
>   bits of  noise  in  the  entropy pool.
>   From this entropy pool random numbers
>   are created.
>
> When  read,  the /dev/random device
>   will only return random bytes within
>   the estimated number of bits of noise
>   in the entropy pool.  /dev/random
>   should be suitable for uses that need 
>   very  high  quality randomness  such 
>   as  one-time  pad  or  key 
>   generation.  **When the entropy pool
>   is empty, reads from /dev/random will
>   block** until additional environmental
>   noise is gathered.
>
> **A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for more
>   entropy**.  As a result,  if  there is
>   not sufficient entropy in the entropy
>   pool, the returned values are
>   theoretically vulnerable to a
>   cryptographic attack on the algorithms
>   used by the driver.  Knowledge of how
>   to do this is not available in the
>   current unclassified literature, but
>   it is theoretically possible that such
>   an attack may exist.  If this is a
>   concern in your application, use
>   /dev/random instead.

both uses a PRNG, though using environmental data and entropy pool makes it astronomically much more difficult to crack the PRNG, and impossible without also gathering the exact same environmental data.

As a rule of thumb, without specialized expensive hardware that gathers data from, say, quantum events, there is no such thing as true random number generator (i.e. a RNG that generates truly unpredictable number); though for cryptographic purpose, /dev/random or /dev/urandom will suffice (the method used is for a CPRNG, cryptographic pseudo-random number generator).

The entropy pool and blocking read of /dev/random is used as a safe-guard to ensure the impossibility of predicting the random number; if, for example, an attacker exhausted the entropy pool of a system, it is possible, though highly unlikely with today's technology, that he can predict the output of /dev/urandom which hasn't been reseeded for a long time (though doing that would also require the attacker to exhaust the system's ability to collect more entropies, which is also astronomically improbably).

Comment: @Lie, So where does the OS store the `/dev/random` bits? Is there a limit to how many of these bits they store?

Comment: @Pacerier, the random.c manpage and corresponding source is well commented and quite interesting: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c

Comment: @LieRyan You mentioned *As a rule of thumb..*. Can you suggest any credible sources for this which could be referred to?

Answer (score 33):

Actually what you need in practice is what FreeBSD's `/dev/urandom` provides: it will read an initial seed of sufficient length from `/dev/random`, then use a PRNG. Thus, it may block initially (just after system boot) but once it has gathered enough entropy, it never blocks. This provides the level of randomness needed by most cryptographic protocols, while not unduly blocking.

Linux's `/dev/urandom` is similar except that it will never block, and thus may risk returning low-quality randomness if used just after boot. On the other hand, `/dev/random` may block even long after boot-time, which is also a problem. I have often seen servers stall mysteriously, because some software was insisting on using `/dev/random`, and the keyboard-less server was not getting enough entropy.

Usual Linux distribution save at shutdown a random seed obtained from `/dev/urandom`, and inject it back upon next boot, thus guaranteeing the quality of the random provided by `/dev/urandom`. Only during OS installation does cryptographic quality becomes an issue, and usually it is not because installation involves a number of interactions with the human being who performs the installation, yielding hordes of entropy.

To sum up, under both Linux and FreeBSD, you should use `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random`.

Comment: Considering that /dev/random is considered to be less secure than /dev/urandom, couldn't it be suggested that this is a less secure approach due to the initial seed relying on /dev/random?

Comment: no /dev/urandom is less secure than /dev/urandom because /dev/urandom does not block when it is out of entropy

Comment: @Demetri — You just said that /dev/urandom is less secure than itself.

Comment: @ToddLehman sorry I meant that /dev/random is (theoretically) more secure.

Comment: And now Linux has a [`getrandom`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) syscall for this purpose. :)

Answer (score 9):

Quoting [here](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/191/device-dev-random-vs-urandom/)

> `/dev/random` will block after the entropy pool is exhausted. It will remain blocked until additional data has been collected from the sources of entropy that are available. This can slow down random data generation.
>
> `/dev/urandom` will not block. Instead it will reuse the internal pool to produce more pseudo-random bits.

---

`/dev/urandom` is best used when:

- You just want a large file with random data for some kind of testing.
- You are using the `dd` command to wipe data off a disk by replacing it with random data.
- Almost everywhere else where you don’t have a really good reason to use `/dev/random` instead.

`/dev/random` is likely to be the better choice when:

- Randomness is critical to the security of cryptography in your application – one-time pads, key generation.